# iterate over json array elements in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, plpgsql

I've got a json that looks like this

```
{
    "elements": [ "element1", "element2", "element3" ]
}
```

I want to iterate over its element and print them.
I do it like this

```
do $$
declare
    datajson jsonb := '{
        "elements": [ "element1", "element2", "element3", "element4" ]
    }';
    element varchar(128);
begin
    foreach element in array jsonb_array_elements(datajson->'elements')
    loop
        raise notice '%', element;
    end loop;
end;
$$;
```

But it fails with the error `query select jsonb_array_elements(datajson->'elements') returned more than one row`.

What is the problem?

**UPDATE**

Tried this suggestion:

```
do $$
declare
    datajson jsonb := '{
        "elements": [ "element1", "element2", "element3", "element4" ]
    }';
    element varchar(128);
begin
    foreach element in array
        SELECT array_agg(jsonb_array_elements) FROM jsonb_array_elements(datajson->'elements')
    loop
        raise notice '%', element;
    end loop;
end;
$$;
```

But that just gives a syntax error:

```
ERROR:  42601: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 7:     SELECT array_agg(jsonb_array_elements) FROM jsonb_array_...
            ^
LOCATION:  scanner_yyerror, scan.l:1134
```

Trying to do this without using `FOR r IN (...)` and declaring a `RECORD` variable.

Answer (score 9):

just:

```
so=# with c(j) as (values('{
    "elements": [ "element1", "element2", "element3" ]
}'::jsonb))
select jsonb_array_elements(j->'elements') from c;
 jsonb_array_elements
----------------------
 "element1"
 "element2"
 "element3"
(3 rows)
```

but if you want to raise it:

```
so=# do $$
declare
    datajson jsonb := '{
        "elements": [ "element1", "element2", "element3", "element4" ]
    }';
    element varchar(128);
    r record;
begin
    for r in (select jsonb_array_elements(datajson->'elements') element)
    loop
        raise notice '%', r.element;
    end loop;
end;
$$;
NOTICE:  "element1"
NOTICE:  "element2"
NOTICE:  "element3"
NOTICE:  "element4"
DO
```

I assume you confuse json array with postgres array - they are not the same. And `jsonb_array_elements` [returns setof](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), not the array

Comment: what to do if each entry has its own subarray in a field like `{ "name" : "value", "fields": ["a1", "a2"] }`?

Comment: write a recursive CTE I'd say

Comment: Thanks - I know how to do it with `FOR r IN (...)` but I was hoping to avoid declaring a `RECORD` variable.

Answer (score 2):

`jsonb_array_elements()` returns elements of array as table, not as array.

Use

```
FOR element IN
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements FROM jsonb_array_elements(datajson->'elements')
LOOP
     ...
END LOOP;
```

to iterate over table rows, not array.

Or use `array_agg()` to convert a table into array:

```
FOREACH element IN ARRAY
    (SELECT array_agg(jsonb_array_elements) FROM jsonb_array_elements(datajson->'elements'))
LOOP
     ...
END LOOP;
```

but it *may* work slower (table will be created as in previous case, and then will be converted)

Comment: so basically it returns a table with a single column? can I convert it into array?

Comment: Yes. Edited the answer.

Comment: The second example does not work: getting `ERROR:  42601: syntax error at or near "SELECT"` - using version 11. Also tried putting the sub-query in parenthesis but same result.

Comment: @user9645 please check if you did not forget `LOOP ... END LOOP;`. Note that I do not have Postgres 11 to test the answer.

Comment: I did not forget the loop/end loop - I just pasted your `FOREACH element in ARRAY SELECT...` statement into my test case and get `ERROR:  42601: syntax error at or near "SELECT"` `LINE 7:     SELECT array_agg(jsonb_array_elements) FROM jsonb_array_...` `LOCATION:  scanner_yyerror, scan.l:1134`  I suggest you verify that you can use `ARRAY` against a `SELECT` statement like that.

Answer (score 0):

json_array_elements_text ( json ) → setof text

jsonb_array_elements_text ( jsonb ) → setof text

> FOR element IN
> SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(datajson->'elements')
> LOOP
> ...
> END LOOP;

'element' has to be declared as a TEXT.
Now we can use element as a TEXT inside the LOOP.